# Render a component from outside ReactJS

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-async

From [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) :

**"The only way to get a handle to a React Component instance outside of React is by storing the return value of React.render."**

I need to render a React component outside React and the reason for it I'm going to  mention below.

In my node.js, expressJS app, I am using ['react-router-component'](https://github.com/STRML/react-router-component) and ['react-async'](https://github.com/andreypopp/react-async).

In app.js -the file which is supposed to be run ,

```
    var url=require('url');   
    var App=require('./react/App.jsx');
    var app = express();
    app.get('*',function(req,res){


    //}); SEE EDIT 1 BELOW

    var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
                ReactAsync.renderComponentToStringWithAsyncState(App({path:path}),function(err, markup) {
    res.send('<!DOCTYPE html>'+markup);

          });
   });
```

In App.jsx,

```
   PostList = require('./components/PostList.jsx');
   var App = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
        return (

           <html>
           <head lang="en">
           </head>
        <body>
        <div id="main">

        <Locations path={this.props.path}>

          <Location path="/" handler={PostList} />
          <Location path="/admin" handler={Admin} />
        </Locations>


       <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/react/bundle.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/custom.js"></script>                 

        </body>
        </html>
        });
```

`bundle.js`  is the browserified file from all the `.jsx` files.

In PostList.jsx,

```
    var PostList = React.createClass({

        mixins: [ReactAsync.Mixin],

        getInitialStateAsync: function(cb) {

           if(typeof this.props.prods==='undefined'){

            request.get('http://localhost:8000/api/cats_default', function(response) {

                    cb(null, {items_show:response.body});

                       });
                                                    }
        },

        setTopmostParentState: function(items_show){

          this.setState({
             items_show:items_show
                       });

         },

        render: function() {

        return (

              <div className="postList" id="postList">
              **// Things go here** 
              <div className="click_me" >Click me</div>
              </div>    
            }

    });


    PostListRender=function(cart_prods){

        var renderNow=function(){

            //return <PostList  cart_prods={cart_prods}></PostList>

             React.renderComponent(<PostList  cart_prods={cart_prods}></PostList>,document.getElementById('postList') );  
                                 };

         return {
           renderNow:renderNow
                }   
        };
    module.exports=PostList;
```

In custom.js:

```
$('.click_me').click(function(){

PostListRenderObj=PostListRender(products_cart_found);
PostListRenderObj.renderNow();

$('odometer').html('price');// price variable is calculated anyhow

});
```

The page shows well.

**EDIT 3 Starts**

Now I want to render the `PostList` component on clicking the `click_me div` .

**EDIT 3 Ends**

But when I click on the `click_me` element, the browser shows script busy, console shows

***ReactJS - ReactMount: Root element has been removed from its original container. New container***

And the Firebug log limit exceeds.

**So why I want to render on click from outside react.js:**
I have to run the jQuery [Odomoeter](http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/) plugin on clicking the `click_me div`. The plugin was not developed as a node middleware **although** it can be installed the way a middleware is installed and the plugin codebase is saved inside `node_modules` folder.

**Edit2 Starts:**

As the plugin is not a node middleware, I cannot `require` it from inside node. However I can perform the click event (code not shown ) from inside node and  run the following code there as well :

```
$('odometer').html('price');// price variable is calculated anyhow
```

In this case I include the plugin in the browser with `<script />` tag and the browserified `bundle.js` comes after the plugin script . But the animation is not properly shown. So I take to the client side click event in the `custom.js`.

<strike>If I do not `require` the plugin to be a middleware from inside node
   and just include it in the page before the browserified JS file and
   perform the click event inside React, then the odometer animation is
   not properly shown.</strike>

**Edit2 Ends:**

So what is the way to render the `PostList` React component outside React ?

**EDIT 1** The `});` was quite mistakenly placed there

Comment: It's quite difficult to tell what you're asking/trying to do here, and I think there might have been some copy/paste issues as the code isn't valid as written. Do you have a JSFiddle, GitHub project, or some other actually working (or not-quite-working) example?

Comment: @BrandonTilley, I pasted only the relevant part here. I need only the logic however. What problems do you find ?

Comment: @BrandonTilley, The page shows up in browser as expected. Now on clicking a `div` in the page from client side React,  I want to re-render the page. This is all I want to do. The `click` event will take place from client side. The reason as to why I do not trigger the `click` from within React is that I have to run a jQuery plugin namely odometer on each click and if I trigger it from within React in server side, I can not run the plugin properly from there as  the plugin is not a node middleware. Anything more to explain ?

Comment: Hi Istiaque. You had requested that I take a look at this on one of my other React answers. I am sorry but I am not able to help here. I have not used React with Node.js or React-router. Sorry.

Comment: Though I have great experience with React I don't have any with react-router or react-async. Anyhow, its seems a bit odd that you define the routing _inside_ a components `render` function (App.jsx).

Answer (score 5):

I cannot understand your question description, but this answers the title question:

***How you render React components outside of react?***

```
MyComponent = require('MyComponent')

element = document.getElementById('postList');

renderedComp = ReactDOM.render(MyComponent,{...someProps},element); 

// => render returns the component instance.

$(document).on('something, function(){
   renderedComp.setState({thingClicked: true})
})
```

Inside of react you can just call the component.