# Vertical dot navigation via ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I've been trying to implement vertical dot navigation on my ReactJS project and i tried to implement this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aybalasubramanian/rpkzxs3d/) which implements it using jquery.

```
    $(document).ready(function($){
          var parPosition = [];
        $('.par').each(function() {
            parPosition.push($(this).offset().top);
        });

        $('a').click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
            }, 500);
            return false;
        });

            $('.vNav ul li a').click(function () {
            $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
        }); 

       $('.vNav a').hover(function() {
           $(this).find('.label').show();
           }, function() {
           $(this).find('.label').hide();
       });

           $(document).scroll(function(){
        var position = $(document).scrollTop(),
                index; 
                for (var i=0; i<parPosition.length; i++) {
                if (position <= parPosition[i]) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
      $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
            $('.vNav ul li a:eq('+index+')').addClass('active');
        });

            $('.vNav ul li a').click(function () {
            $('.vNav ul li a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
        });   
    });
```

It didn't work. It took a while for me to realize that jquery dom manipulation and ReactJS don't really work that well together. I did some searching and i found this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304288/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-jquery-in-react) where the answer confirmed this as well.

Has anyone tried doing this before? I couldn't find one anywhere

thanks

Comment: why are using jquery with react?

Comment: @AmitChauhan more of a late realization than anything. I've not had a lot of experience with ReactJS so it took a while for me to realize that it won't work. I couldn't figure out how to get vertical dot navigation working for ReactJS and i couldn't find a solution online either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used the package [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll) and this worked wonderfully for us.