# Model won't update unless it hits a breakpoint

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this 2 variables:

```
scopeReceiving.selectedBillet.Fee = rowData.Fee;
scopeReceiving.selectedBillet.Interest = rowData.Interest;
```

These are their view:

```
<input id="exemptFee" class="form-control" onchange="calculateExampt()" type="text" min="0" ng_model="selectedBillet.Fee" format="currency" number-input />
<input id="exemptInterest" class="form-control" onchange="calculateExampt()" type="number" min="0" ng_model="selectedBillet.Interest" format="currency" number-input />
```

the Fee is aways showing the number 5 instead of the passed value and Interest is displaying correctly:

[image]

I searched the code and in no place I'm setting this number 5 value. If the code hits a breakpoint it shows correctly. Other way to show is to put a 500ms delay on the variable, but it's an ungly solution and it works only once:

[image]

I have no idead of why this is happening.

I already searched for the id of the form and scopevalues nothing is being set on the whole code, I tried everything, $apply(), $digest(), changing coding order, etc.., nothing works.

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: `onchange` is native property, try to use `ng-change` instead

Comment: Thanks, but the function is not the problem, but I tried anyway and id didn't work. The variable scopeReceiving.selectedBillet.Fee is receiving the 5300 value, but its showing as 5 on the view unless I put a timer on it or it hits a breaking point before executing

Comment: Ok, could you please share how do you apply this changes? `scopeReceiving.selectedBillet.Interest = rowData.Interest`

Comment: I'm not doing anything different from on another.

...

function examptFeesAndInterest(row) {
    var rowData = $('#grid-billets').jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);

    scopeReceiving.selectedBillet.originalBillet.Fee = rowData.Fee;
    scopeReceiving.selectedBillet.originalBillet.Interest = rowData.Interest;

    scopeReceiving.selectedBillet.Fee = rowData.Fee;
    scopeReceiving.selectedBillet.Interest = rowData.Interest;

        $.popup({
         //...opening pop-up
        });
    });
}

Comment: Mixing jQuery and Angular... well that's the problem. Solution : remove jQuery. Or Angular. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304288/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-jquery-in-react/51304632)

Comment: Yes, don't use jquery or any lib that manipulates the DOM. Do that in angular.