# How to disable 2 options in multiselect dropdown and grayout that option

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Hi i have used Angular8 and bootstrap 4. I have used bootstrap multi-select dropdown, i need to get the PL Marketing and CL Marketing as disabled and grayed out. i have tried in all ways but not able to disable and gray out that option.

TS:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initEoForm();
    setTimeout(() => {
      $("#multiselectUser")
        .multiselect({
          buttonWidth: "400px"
        })
        .on("change", e => {
          let selectedFilename = $("#multiselectUser").val();
          selectedFilename = selectedFilename.filter(function(
            item,
            index,
            inputArray
          ) {
            return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
          });
          let selectedName = selectedFilename
            ? selectedFilename.toString()
            : "";
          this.getSelectedRoles(selectedName);
        });
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#assignedRoles option[value="124"]').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#assignedRoles option[value="123"]').prop("disabled", true);
    });
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <select name="user" id="multiselectUser" multiple="multiple" (change)="selecteduser($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedUsers" >
              <option *ngFor="let field of user" [value]="field.id" >
                  {{field.label}}</option>
          </select>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjcakg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Had you tried to use the `[disabled]` over the `<option>` element ?

Comment: @ХристиянХристов Thanks for response, but here i am looping values so wanted to disable via Ts

Comment: So the `users[]` is something comming from some back-end and you want dynamicaly to decide which fields from that array shoulld be disabled, correct?

Comment: Yet somebody else mixing Angular and jQuery together. Please people, [stop doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304288/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-jquery-in-react#:~:text=No.,deleting%20stuff%20into%2Ffrom%20them.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend instead of editing the UI with jQuery to modify the `user[]` that is visualized in the *ngFor and add a field called disabled.  Then in your template you can do the following

```
 <select name="user" id="multiselectUser" multiple="multiple" (change)="selecteduser($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedUsers" >
              <option *ngFor="let field of user" [disabled]="field.disabled" [value]="field.id" >
                  {{field.label}}</option>
          </select>
```

And your typescript should be changed like so

// From

```
   setTimeout(() => {
      $('#assignedRoles option[value="124"]').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#assignedRoles option[value="123"]').prop("disabled", true);
    });
```

// To

```
   setTimeout(() => {
      this.user = this.user.map(x => {
        return {
          ...x,
          disabled: [123, 124].includes(x.id)
        };
      });
```

Here is also a demo on [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-fields-stack-overflow?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (im using your example as base)

// Answer for the comments
You can add a custom class like so and apply whatever styles you need

```
    <option *ngFor="let field of user" [ngClass]="{'disabled-option': field.disabled}"  [disabled]="field.disabled" [value]="field.id" >
                  {{field.label}}</option>
```

And in order to enable the options, you just have to iterate over the fields again and change the disabled state

** Important

Because you are using third party linrary for the select you must add you styles in the root `.css` files for them to take effect.

Also because of the library you are using you should re-initialized the select component in order for it to re-render the options with their new state.

Look again at the stackblitz i had provided

Comment: Thanks for answer, is there anyway to make those value labels also to be grayed out, i mean background color change? and how to enable it back?

Comment: Check out the edit, anyways i think that you should do your own custom dropdown-select instead of using this plugin, because it seems kind of buggy.

Comment: No tutorial ever includes jQuery on top of Angular (or if they do, they have no idea what they are doing). The solution to your problem is to use Angular, OR use jQuery, but not both at the same time.

Comment: @ХристиянХристов in my case, i have used reactive forms, but i am not able to refresh the html based on disabled as true or false, any help on this?

Comment: Do you call the following function `this.prepSelect();` as i do in the stackblitz that I've provided?