# How to manipulate HTML strings without removing misplaced tags?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

I want to manipulate some [HTML strings](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString), by jQuery, in the `compile` function of an AngularJS directive. This is a demo:

```
console.log( getBuiltHtml( '<div><my-directive /></div>' ) );
console.log( getBuiltHtml( '<tr><my-directive /></tr>' ) );

function getBuiltHtml( html ) {
    return $( '<div>' )
        .html( html )
        .find( 'my-directive' )
            .attr( 'ng-repeat', '$item in $list' )
        .end()
        .html();
}
```

In the second case, the directive's tag unexpectedly disappears! I understand that it is because `<tr>` cannot contain other one than `<th>` or `<td>`. How can I avoid it?

Comment: You should know that it is a very, very [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304288/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-jquery-in-react#:~:text=No.,deleting%20stuff%20into%2Ffrom%20them.) to use both jQuery and Angular together... It necessary leads to this kind of complicated hacks you are dealing with.

Comment: @JeremyThille, it is AngularJS, not Angular. And then how do you proceed to modify a HTML element?

Comment: What do you mean directive tag disappears ? How can you avoid what specifically?

Comment: @charlietfl, the expected result is: `<tr><my-directive ng-repeat="$item in $list"></my-directive></tr>`.

Comment: You can't control how browser handles invalid markup. You already know that the structure is invalid. jQuery turns that string into a document fragment and the browser determines what to do when it is invalid

Comment: @charlietfl, before I published this question, I already noticed this. I was asking for some alternative?

Comment: Only alternative is use valid markup