# Angular: some styles/jQuery plugins only load properly on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

I download a HTML template and converted it to Angular project following these steps (https://www.freelancingdesign.com/step-by-step-to-convert-html-template-to-angular-7-template/)

When I reload any page everything works fine, but when I navigate between components some plugins (example: owl-carousel) don't work.

angular.json file:

```
"styles": [
          "src/assets/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css",
          "src/assets/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css",
          "src/assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css",
          "src/assets/css/magnific-popup.css",              
          "src/assets/css/select2.min.css",
          "src/assets/css/paymentfont.min.css",
          "src/assets/css/slider-radio.css",
          "src/assets/css/plyr.css",             
          "src/assets/css/main.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "src/assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",  
          "src/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js", 
          "src/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js", 
          "src/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js", 
          "src/assets/js/smooth-scrollbar.js",  
          "src/assets/js/select2.min.js",     
          "src/assets/js/slider-radio.js",    
          "src/assets/js/jquery.inputmask.min.js",             
          "src/assets/js/plyr.min.js",     
          "src/assets/js/main.js"
        ]
```

No errors in dev tools.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please people, [stop using Angular and jQuery together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304288/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-jquery-in-react#:~:text=No.,deleting%20stuff%20into%2Ffrom%20them.).

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I loved that template, and since it doesn't have angular support, I tried to convert it. Sorry!

Comment: no need to be sorry (: I believe any experienced developer who tried to adopt jQuery in the Angular project would advice you against doing it (: