# I want to use jquery in react

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I want to use jquery in react. I have an input field in my project.I'm making a match event with 'this.state.value' in my input field.
In this control, my input borders have green borders if they match, and red borders if they don't.
I want the border to stay with permanent color if there is no match. How can i do it ?

```
<input className={this.state.value1 != this.state.value1.match(/^[a-zA-ZĞÜŞİÖÇğüşiöç]+$/) ? "redBorder inputInfo" : "greenBorder inputInfo"} name="value1"  type="text"  placeholder="Name" value1={this.state.value1} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

This is css :

```css
input[type=text].redBorder:focus{
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the right way to use Jquery in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304288/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-jquery-in-react)

Comment: This is the definition of an X/Y problem

Comment: So take out the requirement that the element have the `:focus` before the red CSS is applied. Involving jQuery is an utterly bizarre idea.

Comment: You're right Quentin but 
my borders have initial color so i need to use focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a state variable to check if the input is valid, and change the classname accordingly. Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-darwin-q0290?file=/src/App.js)

*styles*:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input[type="text"].redBorder {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input[type="text"].greenBorder {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

*Handling Input*:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [inputIsValid, setInputIsValid] = useState(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputValue.length > 0) {
      if (inputValue.match(/^[a-zA-ZĞÜŞİÖÇğüşiöç]+$/)) setInputIsValid(true);
      else setInputIsValid(false);
    } else setInputIsValid(null);
  }, [inputValue]);

  const handleValueChange = (e) => setInputValue(e.target.value);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        className={
          inputIsValid === null
            ? ""
            : inputIsValid
            ? "greenBorder"
            : "redBorder"
        }
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleValueChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.
You may try it on my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-monad-6d4ic?file=/src/styles.css:0-186).

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  let [borderClass, setBorderClass] = useState("");
  let pattern = /^[a-zA-ZĞÜŞİÖÇğüşiöç]+$/;
  let handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === "") {
      setBorderClass("");
    } else {
      if (e.target.value.match(pattern)) {
        setBorderClass("greenborder");
      } else {
        setBorderClass("redborder");
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" className={borderClass} onKeyUp={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.greenborder {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.redborder {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, answered. Yours looks correct as well. Thanks for your interest.