# How to execute this Javascript code in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am making an app using React framework.

So the problem I have here is that I want to execute this JS code in React. It is basically supposed to dynamically show and hide the `<div>`. Here is the code in the `<script>` tag which I want to run using React:

```
<script>
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }

  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

And here is the css -

```
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

And HTML -

```
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I saw in many tutorials that the componentDidMount helps. But it is not working. Also, I find that componentDidMount is quite complicated. So is there an alternative way to run this JS code in React?

Comment: There's really no reason to keep this as direct DOM manipulation. Rewrite it as a state and a conditional operator in the JSX.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. Can you please answer with the code?

Comment: You can use an aerial function in the onClick() to run JS code, although I don't recommend using this

Comment: OK, You have javascript, You have css, You have html. But You have no react here.

You can just host plain old html page with everything (html/css/js) inside, and it will do the job

Comment: When editing your question you should pay attention to if and what changes someone else already does, so that you won't revert it.

Comment: What Quentin is saying is that you are implementing a common antipattern seen by new learners of React or other MV* frameworks. When using MV* frameworks, the paradigm is: 1) Create a data model, 2) Create a view, 3) Bind the data model to the view, 4) Update the data model, which will cause an "automatic" update to the bound view. You should never be doing imperative, direct DOM manipulation-- it fundamentally is not how React is intended to be used, and will cause you pain.  I recommend starting with a tutorial, or looking at how React Bootstrap manages modals. Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: I am telling that I want to run this Javascript code in react

Comment: You **should not** run this JavaScript code in React-- doing direct DOM manipulation in an MV* library is almost always an antipattern.

Comment: @Professor — And we're telling you that doing so is a bad idea and you should learn how to solve the problem the React Way instead of trying to cram the 1990s way into React.

Comment: This particular problem is an *excellent* beginner level problem to use to learn how to do things the React Way.

Comment: Uhh, ok, I guess my question backfired on me,

Comment: I would recommend looking at [this SO answer that provides a more comprehensive explanation of why not to do direct DOM manipulation in MV* frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51304632/6831341).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502898/show-or-hide-element-in-react

Comment: I guess I will do it this way, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this should get You started. Your plain html/js transforms approximately to this. (css left as  is)

```js
class MyModalApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {showModal: false};
    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
  }

  openModal() {
    this.setState({showModal: true});
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.setState({showModal: false});
  }

  render() {
    const style= this.state.showModal ? {display: "block"} : {display: "none"};
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Modal Example</h2>

        {/* <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal --> */}
        <button id="myBtn" onClick={() => this.openModal()}>Open Modal</button>

        {/* <!-- The Modal --> */}
        <div id="myModal" class="modal" style={style}>

          {/* <!-- Modal content --> */}
          <div class="modal-content">
             <span class="close" onClick={() => this.closeModal()}>&times;</span>
             <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyModalApp />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: While the underlying approach was correct, your code had some issues that prevented it from executing.  I have updated the code into a functioning snippet that runs a working demo.