# Calling a function using onclick from a file in my public folder (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, html, next.js

so I'm new to Next.js and I was wondering how to use `onclick` to call a function from an external file in my public folder.

Here is my index.js

```js
import Head from "next/head"
import Script from "next/script"

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <Script src="/hello.js"></Script>
      </Head>
      <p id="hi">Hello World</p>
      <button onclick="hello()">Click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is my hello.js

```js
function hello() {
  document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML = "Hi World";
}
```

P.S. I will need to export it to static HTML so placing the javascript above the return function will not work.

Comment: Read the comment thread on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72305470/how-to-execute-this-javascript-code-in-react#comment127739835_72305470

Comment: I've been trying to solve this for 2 hours, I gave up that's why I'm asking here

Comment: Again, go and read that comment thread. Your entire approach is wrong. Forget about `innerHTML`. Forget about external scripts. Learn about modules, state and JSX. You're working in React now.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
import hello from 'hello'
```

also you need to export your function with export keyword:

```
export function hello() {
  document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML = "Hi World";
}
```