# Creating offcanvas in bootstrap 4 and react

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `div` which I want to always show for long screen devices. For small screen devices, I want to show a button with hamburger menu and slide in the `div` from left edge of the device screen when the hamburge button is clicked. This is possible out of the box with [`offcanvas` property in bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/#live-demo). But, our project uses `"bootstrap": "^4.6.0"` which does not support offcanvas property.

Our current project uses `"react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3"` which does not support `offcanvas` component. However, version react-bootstrap `2.7` does [support offcanvas](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/offcanvas/).

Quick googling lead me to many workarounds which achieves the same with jQuery or some JS: [example-1](https://codepen.io/JacobLett/pen/oddjOb), [example-2](https://www.codeply.com/p?starter=Bootstrap&ex=hB3cuJ3rj4), [example-3](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_off-canvas.asp)

Apart from this, I tried this [react-offcanvas-menu-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-offcanvas-menu-component), but it was giving conflicts in npm packages.

Is it possible to achieve the same with bootstrap-4?
If not, can I achieve the same result without needing to custom write JS and complex CSS? Or is there some library / npm package which allows to achieve the same?

How should I implement offcanvas menu in react in our project (avoiding any major JS framework like jQuery that [follows different paradigm from React's components based paradigm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51304632/13782227))? Or I am without any solution?

Comment: This may help https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/examples/offcanvas/# . Looks like it works for narrow widths as you requested.

Comment: This is the same example as my example-2 link. It also uses jQuery. Cant we do this without jQuery or JS?

Comment: Bootstrap 4's documentation says "Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function. Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript plugins." Bootstrap 4 depends on jQuery itself. If you're using Bootstrap 4, you already include jQuery. Then why is it a problem?

Comment: This is actually a react project and i wanted to avoid jQuery or keep its use to minimal as it [breaks apart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51304632/13782227) from react's component binding paradigm